# Change character column into numeric

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I have a data frame df with a column X where we have three different variables a, b and c as characters. For example

```
df$X <- data.frame(X = c(a,a,a,b,b,c,c,c,c), Y = ....)
```

I want to transform it into a = 1, b = 2 and c = 3 as numerics.

I first tried

```
df$X = as.factor(df$X)
transform(df, X = as.numeric(X))
```

where now I have a factor with three levels and a=1, b=2 and c=3. However the problem is that I need the column X as numeric. If I try

```
transform(df, X = as.numeric(as.character(X)))
```

or

```
transform(df, X = as.numeric(levels(X))[X])
```

I get NA for all the inputs (a, b, c).

How can I get the column X with numeric 1, 2, 3?

Comment: `transform(df, X=as.numeric(as.factor(X)))` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of @jay.sf with encoding the characters first as a factor is quite elegant, because it generalizes to aribitrary strings and not just single characters.

If the codes are single characters, there is another possible solution, which uses the builtin constant `letters` and returns the position therein:

```
sapply(df$X, function(x) {which(x == letters)})
```